# media queries doesnt work, and stuck with other media queries

Tags: html, css, iphone, media-queries

Hello guys i have some problem with media queries. here is my example code

```
/* Landscape iphone 4 */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: landscape) {

    /* ----------------- category page  ----------- */
    .block-content > #narrow-by-list2,
    .block-content.stick-up > #narrow-by-list2{
        width: 450px;
    }
}

/* Landscape iphone 6*/
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 375px)
and (max-device-width: 667px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: landscape) {


    /* ----------------- category page  ----------- */
    .block-content > #narrow-by-list2,
    .block-content.stick-up > #narrow-by-list2{
        width: 637px;
    }

}
```

when i test it my div.block-content always use iphone 6 media-queries css and don`t use iphone 4 media-queries css.can you tell me what im doing wrong.

thanks before

Comment: conditionA **and** conditionB means "A **+** B" so it is only applied on the devices which cover the combination of all your requests. You should use "and" when you need to set a width plus a height, not 2 different widths;

Comment: you are free to set it in the way you want, I'm just saying with "**and**" you're letting your limits very restrict;

Comment: why are you using a combination of several requests at once?

Comment: I think maybe your wish is to use `,` instead of `and`

Comment: because i need targeting each diffrent iphone, can you tell me how i target diffrent iphone using media queries

Comment: There is thousands of mobiles on the market, I think its a better idea you use a single unit to set your limits. The most common used is simply "min-width".

Comment: i try following tutorial from [css-triks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: [**heres a website**](http://troy.labs.daum.net/) to you test your website in different devices.

Comment: use `min-width:` instead of `min-device-width:` so you can test the result shrinking your browser;

Comment: can it work with localhost development? right now im using google chorme device mode

Comment: no troy labs is only online. i think 'adobe device central' is for offline testing (im not quite sure because i have never used it);